# Run NgFor directive without prefix with star

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ngfor

For education purpose only can we run `NgFor` without prefix with star and how we can do it so I can understand how things work ?

and extra information will be very helpful ,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `ng-template` you can. but then have to use `[ngForOf]` along side.

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</ng-template>
```

[DOC](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)